# concatenating by adding an integer without redundancy

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```js
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML)+10
```

```html
<span id="numbers">10</span>
```

But I find it long to be written, so I thought about shortening it using this:

```js
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += 10
```

```html
<span id="numbers">10</span>
```

But it concatenates a string and gives me **1010** instead of **20**.

Can it be shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awful hack:

```js
document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML -= -10
```

```html
<span id="numbers">10</span>
```

Comment: why is it considered awful?

Comment: @JoeDoe: Because the implementation doesn’t relate obviously to the intent. Personally, I’d never include this in a page, and do what David suggested instead, or avoid reading from `innerHTML` entirely if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The only operation you're really repeating is getting the element:

```
document.getElementById('numbers')
```

So extract that to a variable:

```
let el = document.getElementById('numbers');
el.innerHTML = parseInt(el.innerHTML) + 10;
```

Keep in mind that *shorter* code isn't necessarily *better* code.  You can try a variety of hacks that will get the job done, but in many cases you're sacrificing readability and supportability.  Sometimes you even end up relying on undefined behavior, which can differ across browsers or in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your shortened code is adding a 'string' to int (10), JS will understand the operation as adding a 'string' to another 'string' which is a concatenation operation, not an arithmetic operation.
To avoid concatenation operation you should use parseInt() to convert the string to an integer and do an arithmetic operation instead.
You remaining code can't be shortened unless declaring a variable as already mentioned by @Davide